# integrate Assisted-GPS with ionic framwork

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

i developed an ionic app that  can geolocate the user,  it worked fine return the latitude and logitude. the problem is whene the device use a-gps,the app doesn't return any thing.
how can i solve this problem?
is android has an api for a-gps?

```js
 getCurrentPosition(): Promise<Geoposition> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        maximumAge: 10
      };
      console.log('options : ', options);
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((location) => {
        // resp.coords.latitude
        // resp.coords.longitude
        resolve(location)
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }// getCurrentPosition
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried and potential errors in logs. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [How to Create a Minimul, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SimonC  it work very well in phone or tablet but not not with a mobi printer (mobiwire) that use a-gps insteat of standard  gps